# Disappearing custom markers - google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a map with custom markers.

When heights and widths are all the same, everything works fine. If I change one of them to be bigger (2x), that marker starts to behave funny - it's partially rendered on map, it disappears and reappears when zooming in/out, on some zoom levels it looks ok. Input images are all 128x128, I am scaling them to 32x32 but i would like some of them to be 64x32

Here's main function for adding markers (I commented out things that I tried before):

```
jQuery(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
var name = jQuery(this).find('name').text();
var address = jQuery(this).find('address').text();

// create a new LatLng point for the marker
var lat = jQuery(this).find('lat').text();
var lng = jQuery(this).find('lng').text();
var twidth = jQuery(this).find('width').text();
var theight = jQuery(this).find('height').text();
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));
var imgPath = jQuery(this).find('icon').text();

var hw = twidth/2;
var hh = theight/2;
var imageForMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    imgPath,
    null,     //new google.maps.Size(128, 128),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    null,     //new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is at the centre
    null,    //new google.maps.Point(hw, hh),
    // Scaled size
    new google.maps.Size(twidth, theight));

    // extend the bounds to include the new point
    MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: MYMAP.map,
            icon: imageForMarker,
            zIndex:0
        });

        citiesArray.push(marker);

        var html='<strong>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+address+'<br><img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=http%3A//maps.google.com/maps%3Fq=%26ll%3D'+lat+'%2C'+lng+'%26z%3D14&chld=H|0">';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        if(infoWindow)
            infoWindow.close();
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            infoWindow.setContent(html);

            infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);


        });

        MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);

    });
```

xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers>

<marker>
<name>name1</name>
<address></address>
<lat>54.721844</lat>
<lng>17.41024</lng>
<width>32</width>
<height>32</height>
<icon>park2.png</icon>
</marker>

( ...)

<marker>
<name>name2</name>
<address></address>
<lat>50.417408112618686</lat>
<lng>23.491015625</lng>
<width>32</width>
<height>32</height>
<icon>park.png</icon>
</marker>

</markers>
```

here's MYEDIT definition + initialization:

var infoWindow;
   var MYMAP = {
    map: null,
    bounds: null,
    iWindow: null
   }

```
MYMAP.init = function(selector, latLng, zoom) {
var myOptions = {
zoom:zoom,
center: latLng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
this.map = new google.maps.Map(jQuery(selector)[0], myOptions);
this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}
```

test bed is at:

http://null-zero.com/test/markers/markers.html

IMPORTANT: you have to scroll down, tick CITIES, then at the top of the map near GDANSK a castle should appear - it's broken (top part of the castle is visible), strange things happen when you zoom in/out.

There are two PlaceMarkers functions - the bottom one uses different width/height and is broken (placeMarkersCities)

Any ideas what causes it and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I think I might be having a similar issue.

Comment: I wonder if the question might get a better response if it was edited so that the problem description was at the top of the question, before the big chunks of code? If that doesn't work, we might need to set a bounty on it.

Comment: Did you check that hh and hw are integers? I don't have jQuery here, so I cannot test your code. A link to a live demo page would be useful.

Comment: I've added MYMAP definition + initialization

Comment: Adde test bed as well - at the bottom of description ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is

```
var twidth = jQuery(this).find('width').text();
var theight = jQuery(this).find('height').text();
...
new google.maps.Size(twidth, theight));
```

But `Size` takes two **Numbers**. Odd things have been known to happen when maps objects are fed the wrong parameter type. In this case, you only convert some data from Strings to Numbers. You don't convert `twidth` and `theight`.

I suggest converting the data when you read it

```
var lat = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find('lat').text());
var lng = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find('lng').text());
var twidth = parseInt(jQuery(this).find('width').text());
var theight = praseInt(jQuery(this).find('height').text());
```

rather than when you use it (as in your current code)

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));
```

because then it's done once and you don't have to remember it.

Comment: oh dear, you are right ;) I thought javascript is able to convert stuff on the fly, I guess I was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Javascript *does* convert on the fly: `"32"/2 = 16`. But you can't assume the API does that for you.